# Intellij JPA console: configure persistence.xml for H2 in-memory database

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, jhipster

I am trying to use the JPA console in Intellij Idea Ultimate for testing queries. The project is generated with JHipster 5.7.0 and uses an H2 in-memory database with Hazelcast.

**generated application-dev.yml:**

```
...
datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:appointmentservice;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        username: appointmentservice
        password:
        hikari:
            auto-commit: false
    h2:
        console:
            enabled: true
    jpa:
        database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedH2Dialect
        database: H2
        show-sql: false
        properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
            hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name: appointmentservice
            hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts: true
            hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_lite_member: true
...
```

I created the following **persistence.xml** in my resources directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="appointmentservice" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:appointmentservice"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="appointmentservice"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name" value="appointmentservice"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_lite_member" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The following configuration works in the H2 web console:
[image]

**The problem:**
In the Intellij persistence view all entites show up, when clicking on appointmentservice. However when I right click it and open a JPA console, all queries fail claiming, that the tables were not found.

e.g.

```
jpa-ql> select a from Address a
[2019-03-04 16:03:57] [42S02] Table "ADDRESS" not found; SQL statement:
[2019-03-04 16:03:57] select address0_.id as id1_1_, address0_.active as active2_1_, address0_.city as city3_1_, address0_.clientAccount_id as clientAc9_1_, address0_.country as country4_1_, address0_.institution_id as institu10_1_, address0_.location_id as locatio11_1_, address0_.jhi_number as jhi_numb5_1_, address0_.street as street6_1_, address0_.supplement as suppleme7_1_, address0_.zip as zip8_1_ from address address0_ [42102-197]
```

I would much appreciate if someone could give me a hint what I'm doing wrong, or if there are any good example persistence.xml files for my case.
Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
Thank for all the responses!
 - I followed the suggestions of @Gaël Marziou and deleted persistence.xml and used the tcp URL to connect to the datasource in Intellij. There I now can browse the table contents.
I then had to assign the datasource to the entityManagerFactory in the Intellij persistence view. Furthermore I needed to use the same NamingStrategie as in application.yml.

Comment: There is nothing wrong here. However you are using an in-memory database which is only visible to the running process. It isn't externally accessible. Hence you will not see the same database in Intellij.

Comment: So this also means I can't access it even with the application running?

Comment: No, unless you configure it using the tCP port (as stated in the answer below). Or by simply not overriding the property. I would also suggest to drop the `persistence.xml` in favor of the `application.properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHipster creates the H2 server with a TCP port (see `h2TCPServer()` method in `DatabaseConfiguration.java`), so your in-memory database is accessible from an external client using a tcp JDBC url which is different from the one configured in your `application.yml`.

The external client should use `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:18080/mem:appointmentservice`

The port 18080 is based on the web port (e.g. 8080) + 10000 (see `h2TCPServer()` method) and is logged at application startup as "H2 database is available on port xxxxx".

Personally I use DBeaver to access the H2 database in my JHipster apps.

As advised by M. Deinum, you should delete `persistence.xml`.

Comment: If he would use the default, but he reconfigured the URL.

Comment: What do you mean? I can't see any change in what has been generated by JHipster. As long as he did not modify DatabaseConfiguration class generated by JHipster, my tip should work.

Comment: He changed the URL in the properties file and that has precedence.

Comment: No he did not change it, it's what is generated and it works well with what I have described.

Comment: Yes he did. Look at both the `applicaiton.yaml` and `persistence.xml` he posted. That clearly has a different URL. Also the server is only started when the dev profile is active not by default.

Comment: Oh you meant the URL params, as you advised he should delete persistence.xml. About the dev profile, it is set by default by maven or gradle in generated project, so if he uses the project as documented he should be fine.